# Would you help me understand the meaning of this excerpt

Tags: meaning-in-context

I started to read Mark Twain's book titled as "[Adventures of Huckleberry Finn](https://books.google.com/books?id=hlGFO05zTAkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT11#v=onepage&q&f=false)". At the very beginning of the book I came across with this sentence:

> *I never seen anybody but lied one time or another, without it was Aunt Polly, or the widow, or maybe the Mary.*

Now I have two questions:

1. Is that "I never seen" part correct? Does it have anything to do with the dialect?
2. I cannot fully get the meaning of the sentence; Would you please tell me the meaning of the sentence in plain English. Particularly, I have problem with the "but" and "without it" parts.

Comment: As for your first question: It has **everything** to do with dialect. Plan to see a lot more of this kind of language if you plan on finishing this book – particularly between quotation marks.

Comment: Interesting this quote has a "," between "lied" and "one time", many don't have the comma.  This [commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=A5gi23_jlOUC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=I+never+seen+anybody+but+lied,+one+time+or+another,+without+it+was+Aunt+Polly,+or+the+widow,+or+maybe+the+Marry&source=bl&ots=vczMAGTOQU&sig=STAnBmTrJ5p1Q7ZxIbO6P4z-gDM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4tKyO0ozRAhVqyoMKHXCUCrYQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=I%20never%20seen%20anybody%20but%20lied%2C%20one%20time%20or%20another%2C%20without%20it%20was%20Aunt%20Polly%2C%20or%20the%20widow%2C%20or%20maybe%20the%20Marry&f=false) may help you.

Comment: These are the sort of "substandard" speech characteristics that are supposed to be eradicated by *book learnin'*.  I've never seen anyone but (he or she) had lied at one time or another, i.e. who *had not lied* at some time in his or her life.  Without it was  = except.  Regional dialects can preserve speech characteristics which get eroded from the dialect that rises to become the "standard" dialect. These uses of **but** and **without** are very old ones.

Comment: @TRomano I see. That was difficult for me to unravel those "but" and "without".

Answer (score 3):

The idea can be phrased like the following :

> I never met anybody who didn't lie from time to time. I think the only exceptions were Aunt Polly,the widow and Mary.

He is not sure about Mary though.(Don't use *the* before the name). I think the author wants to show that the boy is not educated and homeless. Nobody taught him.It's a literary device based on a dialect."Without it" means without this fault"(lying).

Comment: Possibly **the Mary** is a respectful reference to **the Virgin Mary**? For sure it's not standard English, to say **the <name>**. I'm wondering whether **without it** is actually meaning **except for**, the implication being a rising hierarchy of very special women.

Comment: "*the* Mary"  is a term of familiarity/endearment which is not current in standard English.  Compare German "*der* Johann" or "*die* Greta", and "without" means "excepting"; and **it** there is expletive aka "dummy *it*".

Comment: There's no article in the original text.